# Open graph actions suddenly not working properly

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I had an action which used to work fine until today morning but now its not behaving the way it should.

Facebook is not catching variables that i send after "index.jsp?". Because of which though the actions are published it show it shows null for the puzzle id and timing.

[image]

Below are codes i tried both gave me same issues.

```
 FB.api('/me/mpuzzleapp:solve?mpuzzle='+encodeURIComponent('{mycompleteurl}/index.jsp?mid='+mid+'&timing='+timing+'&access_token='+accessToken),'post', 
      function(response) {                                                                                  
        if (!response || response.error) {
              //alert(response.error.message);
          }else{ 
              alert("Action posted successfully.")
          }
      });


 FB.api(
        '/me/mpuzzleapp:solve',
        'post',
        {
          mpuzzle: '{mycompleteurl}/index.jsp?mid='+mid+'&timing='+timing+'&access_token='+accessToken
        },
        function(response) {
          if (!response || response.error) {
              alert(response.error.message);
          }else{ 
              alert("Action posted successfully.")
          }
        }
      );
```

Previously this used to work fine, Now it is just not able to catch parameter with my url. the link that was posted in my wall is this.

https://apps.facebook.com/mpuzzleapp/index.jsp?fb_action_ids=10151927328076515&fb_action_types=mpuzzleapp%3Asolve&fb_source=timeline_og&action_object_map=%7B%2210151927328076515%22%3A401787199906324%7D&action_type_map=%7B%2210151927328076515%22%3A%22mpuzzleapp%3Asolve%22%7D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D

it is missing mid and timing parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change my  og:url tag and it worked perfect :

Old :

```
 <meta property="fb:app_id" content="278272228942900" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"   content="mpuzzleapp:mpuzzle" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="https://apps.facebook.com/mpuzzleapp/index.jsp" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="MPuzzle 3" /> 
  <meta property="mpuzzleapp:to" content="friends" /> 
  <meta property="mpuzzleapp:timing" content="00:00:45" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"  content="https://www.vishweshshetty.com/Facebook/puzzlemsg/65/images/icon.jpg" />
```

New :

```
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="278272228942900" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"   content="mpuzzleapp:mpuzzle" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="https://apps.facebook.com/mpuzzleapp/index.jsp?mid=3&timing=00:00:45"&tolist=friends&pathpic=https://www.vishweshshetty.com/Facebook/puzzlemsg/65/images/icon.jpg" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="MPuzzle 3" /> 
  <meta property="mpuzzleapp:to" content="friends" /> 
  <meta property="mpuzzleapp:timing" content="00:00:45" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"  content="https://www.vishweshshetty.com/Facebook/puzzlemsg/65/images/icon.jpg" />
```